# How to password protect NFC NTAG215 tags using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

As part of my project requirement, I want to password-protect my NFC tag to prevent overwriting. I searched a lot over the internet, but I couldn't find any reliable guides or articles that explained in Xamarin. So if anyone has done password protection of NFC tags using Xamarin, please guide me.

Comment: do you know how to password protect them natively?

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I got some references for Android, but I can't find any code for iOS. If you have any, please share!

Comment: I sucessfully password protected my NTAG21x by reading the datasheet very carefully (on Android using Java, sorry).

Comment: @Jason Would it be possible for you to share your code example here, that would be extremely helpful for me.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following steps in Xamarin.Android for adding password protection in NFC NTAG215 tags

1. Add the changes to your code based on the [Plugin.NFC](https://github.com/franckbour/Plugin.NFC) documentation.
2. Add the following methods to your MainActivity.cs class to check, add and remove password configuration for your tag.

```cs
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, NFCTagConfiguration
{
    public Tag maintag;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CrossNFC.Init(this);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        // Plugin NFC: Restart NFC listening on resume (needed for Android 10+) 
        CrossNFC.OnResume();
    }

    protected override async void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        maintag = (Tag)intent.GetParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.ExtraTag);
        // Plugin NFC: Tag Discovery Interception
        CrossNFC.OnNewIntent(intent);
        if (maintag != null)
        {
            ////Handle your logic here
            //1.Check password configuration
            //2.Add password protection
            //3.Remove password protection
        }
    }

    public bool CheckConfiguration()
    {
        bool passExist;
        try
        {
            MifareUltralight mu = MifareUltralight.Get(maintag);
            mu.Connect();
            var answer = mu.ReadPages(131);
            byte auth0 = answer[3];
            passExist = auth0 < (byte)0xEB;
            mu.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            mu.Close();
            passExist = true;
        }
        return passExist;
    }

    public bool AddConfiguration(string PSWD)
    {
        NfcA nfcaTag = NfcA.Get(maintag);
        bool IsConfigured;
        try
        {
            byte[] SET_PACK_VALUE = { (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };
            byte[] PWD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234");
            byte[] SET_PASSWORD = { (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x85, PWD[0], PWD[1], PWD[2], PWD[3] };
            byte[] SET_AUTH0_VALUE = { (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x83, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x04 };
            string pack = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(SET_PASSWORD);
            nfcaTag.Connect();
            nfcaTag.Transceive(SET_PACK_VALUE);
            nfcaTag.Transceive(SET_PASSWORD);
            nfcaTag.Transceive(SET_AUTH0_VALUE);
            nfcaTag.Close();
            IsConfigured = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            nfcaTag.Close();
            IsConfigured = false;
        }
        return IsConfigured;
    }

    public bool RemoveConfiguration(string PSWD)
    {
        byte[] RESET_PACK_VALUE = { (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };
        byte[] RESET_AUTH0_VALUE = { (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x83, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFF };
        byte[] PWD = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234");
        byte[] SET_PASSWORD = { (byte)0x1b, PWD[0], PWD[1], PWD[2], PWD[3] };
        MifareUltralight mfu = MifareUltralight.Get(maintag);
        bool IsConfigured;
        try
        {
            byte[] answer;
            mfu.Connect();
            answer = mfu.Transceive(SET_PASSWORD);  
            mfu.Transceive(RESET_AUTH0_VALUE);
            mfu.Transceive(RESET_PACK_VALUE);
            mfu.Close();
            IsConfigured = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            mfu.Close();
            IsConfigured = false;
        }
        return IsConfigured;
    }
}
```

If you're using other tags, You can refer to the [NTAG 213/215/216 Data sheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf) to know the APDU commands.